# Cant get select to work in mysql! getting weird results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a MySQL database and for some odd reason i cannot select the things i want to select in the database,and its or i get nothing,or i get "Resource id #3"

this is my code and database:

[image]

And for some reason i get things i do not want.

What i actually want is to select the "`type`" row where the "`code`" row is a variable i define.

Now inserting things into the database works flawlessly,so im connected for sure...im really clueless by now and id be happy if you have an idea whats wrong..
i couldnt get any insert command to work.

Thanks

edit:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

whats that all about?

Comment: You are only quering the database and not fetching any data

Comment: isn't it better to add the code into your question rather than taking a picture of it?

Comment: In addition to @Fabio comment if you are starting, you should start to use **PDO or mysqli_** function because **mysql_** functions are deprecated

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query() executes the query.
```

You have to then retrieve the results of your query by looping through them.

You can fetch an array with:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

   echo $row[0];
   //or this
   echo $row["col_name"];

}
```

You can use an integer index, which retrieves col value in the order in which they are selected. Or alternatively, you can retrieve a column of a row by indexing it's column name
Check out more examples here: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: ahm @Azrael it says that mysql_fetch_array() is not a valid mysql result resource or whatever.. whats that?

Comment: Can you post the exact code that gives you this error in your question?

Comment: The query being executed is an insert query. Insert queries don't return a data set. Remove it and the previous select will be executed. Be aware that $row['col_name'] is an example. Replace 'col_name' with the column name you want to retrieve.

Comment: YEs it's an outdated function. As is mysql_connect, mysql_query... They're old and depreciated as of PHP 5.5. The newer methods are with PDO or mysqli. They are more secure. I don't know what your database looks like so I can't be sure about your query. But it's syntax-ally correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use any Mysql_* function anymore since these are decrepated, and consider using something like PDO or prepared statements. But further on topic: try looping your query result:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   $ID = $row['id'];
   $Name = $row['name'];
   echo "ID: $ID Name: $Name";
   }
```

This should return normal values as you desired.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in --- on line 18

Comment: Make sure that the while loop comes after your mysql query.

Comment: You should also edit the fields to your likings, I just gave you an example, for example you would need to retrieve $Type = `$row['Type'];` instead of $ID = `$row['id'];`

Comment: yea,your right! but the fetch array command doesnt even execute properly

Comment: Tried: `($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))` ?

Comment: Mmh then i'm out of idea's, im used to the mysqli_* commands instead of mysql_* since mysql_* is decrepated

Comment: how would i switch to mysqli?

Comment: I would suggest looking on this page: http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/mysqli-procedural-functions/
It has a great explanation for the basic functions of mysqli, and you will notice that it's pretty similar.

Comment: do i need to change anything but the connection? anything on my host?

Comment: Not much, it's that and a little change in your query syntax; instead of `mysql_query("ACTUAL QUERY HERE");` it would be `mysqli_query($connectionvar,"ACTUAL QUERY HERE");`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/euL9U2hZ got a little error,telling me its not mysql or whatever,but im doing it like on the documentation page

Comment: I can't see what's behind getConnected(); so I can't see how your connection is, but it `$connection = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");` should do the trick of connecting and thereby fix your problem.

Comment: getConnected simply connects like you demonstrated above,using mysqli